# Android 1.6 like slider

Tags: android, slider

I need a little help with something that I want to achieve. A want to implement this kind of view in my application :

[image]

like the button at the bottom of the page, and when user touch it, it's slide above and show other content. I'm pretty sure that I've found examples like that before, but now when I needed I couldn't find anything similar.

Any ideas what should I look for or even better if you can show me a link to a similar example I will appreciate that!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this

http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2009/08/android-sliding-drawer-example.html